# Rails i18n tranlate DB table data

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, internationalization

What is the best/correct way to translate for example a product description that is saved in the DB into multiple languages. Will I have to add more fields to the product table like:

```
description_en
description_de
etc...
```

Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is of course not a single correct way, but I personally like the Globalize2 gem: https://github.com/joshmh/globalize2

Comment: Oh and in case you're using Rails 3, be sure to use the rails-3 branch: `gem 'globalize2', :git => 'git://github.com/joshmh/globalize2.git', :branch => 'rails-3'`